# How to clip raster by multiple polygons in multi rasters?

Tags: qgis, python, raster, gdal

Using QGIS, I want to clip a raster by multiple polygons contained in a single shapefile. I read that `gdalwarp` can clip my raster by multiple polygons BUT the output is a single merged clipped raster.

I want to have one clipped raster per polygon. If I have 20 polygons, I want to have 20 clipped rasters at the end :-)

I can't find any option of `gdalwarp` that allows me to do this. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: The easiest way is to use a scripted solution, where you first split your polygon into features and then crop your raster element-wise. What operating system are you using?

Comment: I try to develop a multi-platform QGIS plugin so I use MacOS, Windows and Linux (Ubuntu).

Comment: If you can write scripts then what is the problem? Do you want someone to write a code for you? Aren't you able to clip the same raster 20 times in the cycle?

Comment: I don't want to clip my raster 20 times. I have a shapefile containing x polygons. I want to clip my initial raster by the first polygon and get a new raster output, then, clip my initial raster by the second polygon and get new raster output, and so on ... I can't find how to do this with `gdalwarp`

Comment: @Lambdacrash, pseudocode: (for polygon in layer: clip_initial_raster.by_polygon, save output).

Comment: The use of GRASS GIS could also be a solution. Maybe my answer here can give some advices: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/87153/15459. For selecting your polygons you can use v.select additionally.

Comment: I am doing to same thing, working with the code given in this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769531/gtiff-mask-with-shapefile-in-python-with-gdal-ogr-etc, -- answered May 30 '14 at 9:10 --
Rutger Kassies I have not gotten it to work the way I need it to yet, but it should clip one raster to the one shapefile but the selected attribute in the shapefile, in my case I have a countries shapefile and am clipping by "COUNTRY".

Answer (score 6):

Here's a command line method using [gdalwarp](/questions/tagged/gdalwarp), formulated as a Windows batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set index=D:\source\nts_index_250k.shp
set tiles=117D 117A 116O 116P

for %%a in (%tiles%) do (
  @echo gdalwarp -cutline %index% ^
  -cwhere "'TILE_NAME' = '%%a'" ^
  -cblend 3 ^
  %1 %2_%%a.tif
  )
endlocal
goto :eof
```

**Usage**

```
crop_by_poly.bat infile.tif
```

**Explanation**

As written, the batchfile does no work, just prints to console the commands needed to do the work (remove `@echo` to make it execute instead of print):

```
gdalwarp -cutline D:\source\nts_index_250k.shp   -cwhere "'TILE_NAME' = '117D'"   -cblend 3 dem_20m_shade.tif 117D_dem_20m_shade.tif
gdalwarp -cutline D:\source\nts_index_250k.shp   -cwhere "'TILE_NAME' = '117A'"   -cblend 3 dem_20m_shade.tif 117A_dem_20m_shade.tif
```

**`^`**: line continuation character

**index:**  polygon data source, in the case Canadian National Topographic System tiles

**tiles:** values to select from the polygon feature records. Attribute table looks like:

```
+-----------+-------------------+
| TILE_NAME |       NAME        |
+-----------+-------------------+
| 117C      | Demarcation Point |
| 117D      | Herschel Island   |
| 107C      | Mackenzie Delta   |
+-----------+-------------------+
```

`-cwhere "'TILE_NAME' = '%%a'" ^` : select this or these features from source, becomes `-cwhere "'TILE_NAME' = 117D'"` etc. Be mindful of quotes, outermost must be double and inner must be single, and always in pairs.

`-cblend 3`: optional, expand crop area by 3 pixels, to allow for future seamless overlap/mosaicking

`%1 %2`: becomes `infile.tif outprefix_infile.tif`, so in this example `117D_infile.tif`, `117A_infile.tif`, ...

The output image will have same extent as original raster with the clipped out regions marked as *nodata*. Add the `-crop_to_cutline` option to have set the extent to match the clipping polygon, but be aware that the edge matching is not perfect at this time when used with cblend (gdal issue [#5981](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5981))

---

A python solution was asked for, the logic illustrated with this batchfile could be adapted to python by incorporating [For looping folder to batch clip rasters by polygon using python and QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75086/how-to-for-loop-a-folder-to-batch-clip-rasters-by-polygon-using-python-and-qgis)

Untested and not elegant or pythonic, but should get someone started:

```
from subprocess import call
clipper = r'D:\source\nts_index_250k.shp'
tiles = '117D 117A 116O 116P'.split()
for tile in tiles:
    warp = '''gdalwarp -cutline {clipper} -cwhere "'TILE_NAME' = '{tile}'" {infile} {outfile}'''.format(clipper=clipper,
        tile=tile,
        infile=infile,
        outfile=tile + infile
        )
    call(warp)
```

---

Dear lazy web: The ideal answer to this question would be to operate from inside qgis: select a polygon layer (or selection polys within layer), select a raster, and run *"clip_for_each {selected} {outfolder}"*

Comment: about the lazy web: is this `clip_for_each` a command that exists inside qgis ? If so, where ? :) Thanks

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă _"dear lazy web"_ is a whimsical way of asking/wishing/praying that someone else out there wilds will create and share this missing feature. As far as I know there is no 'clip for each' in qgis, but that's not saying much as I only use qgis about 10% of the time and I don't know much.

Answer (score 0):

I found the first part of the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444015/python-code-review-for-a-function-to-clip-a-raster-image-with-a-polygon). I just have to iterate over features.