# For looping folder to batch clip rasters by polygon using python and QGIS?

Tags: gdal, pyqgis, gdalwarp

I am using Python and QGIS 2.0.

I am trying to clip rasters in a folder by one polygon feature.

It's the first time for me using PyQGIS; I was used to ArcPy before.

How do I get my script to work?

```
import qgis.core, qgis,utils
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

CLIP= "C:/Users/unim/Documents/Umberto/Universita/PhD/Guglielmin/Permafrost/Alta_Valtellina/Landsat_ita/study_area_foscagno.shp"
INPUT_FOLDER="C:/Users/unimi/Documents/Umberto/Universita/PhD/Guglielmin/Permafrost/Alta_Valtellina/Landsat_ita/LE71930282000259EDC00"
OUTPUT= "C:/Users/unim/Documents/Umberto/Universita/PhD/Guglielmin/Permafrost/Alta_Valtellina/Landsat_ita/foscagno_pyqgis/"


for RASTER in INPUT_FOLDER.tif
do
    echo "Processing $RASTER"
    gdalwarp -q -cutline CLIP -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff RASTER OUTPUT+ "clip_"+ RASTER
done

QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

Below are the improvements I've done since now, not getting the script to work though, but I think I might be getting closer.

```
import qgis.core, qgis.utils, os, fnmatch
from osgeo import gdal

CLIP= "C:/Users/unimi/Documents/Umberto/Universita/PhD/Guglielmin/Permafrost/Alta_Valtellina/Landsat_ita/study_area_foscagno.shp"
INPUT_FOLDER= "C:/Users/unimi/Documents/Umberto/Universita/PhD/Guglielmin/Permafrost/Alta_Valtellina/Landsat_ita/LE71930282000259EDC00/DNs2Reflectance_LE71930282000259EDC00"
OUTPUT= "C:/Users/unimi/Documents/Umberto/Universita/PhD/Guglielmin/Permafrost/Alta_Valtellina/Landsat_ita/Cloud_mask_AltaValtellina/clip_2_foscagno"

def findRasters (path, filter):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
            yield os.path.join (root, file)

for raster in findRasters (INPUT_FOLDER, '*.tif'):
    print (raster)
    outRaster = OUTPUT + '/clip_' + raster
    cmd = 'gdalwarp -dstnodata 0 -q -cutline CLIP -crop_to_cutline %s %s' % (raster, outRaster)
    os.system (cmd)
```

I think there might be something wrong in the "gdal" command, as the "print" function does its job properly, but no file is written to the output, neither I receive any error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally managed with this very simple and clean script, which calls GDAL from Python without importing it (as suggested, but using "Call ()" method instead of "os.system ()".

```
import os, fnmatch
from subprocess import call
call(["ls", "-l"])

inFolder= 'C:/Users/unimi/Documents/Umberto/Universita/PhD/Guglielmin/Permafrost/Alta_Valtellina/Landsat_ita/LE71930282000259EDC00/DNs2Reflectance_LE71930282000259EDC00/'
outFolder= 'C:/Users/unimi/Documents/Umberto/Universita/PhD/Guglielmin/Permafrost/Alta_Valtellina/Landsat_ita/Cloud_mask_AltaValtellina/clip_2_foscagno/'

os.chdir (inFolder)

def findRasters (path, filter):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, filter):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
            yield os.path.join (root, file)

for raster in findRasters (inFolder, '*.tif'):
    (infilepath, infilename)= os.path.split (raster)
    print infilename
    outRaster= outFolder+ 'clip_'+ infilename
    print outRaster
    warp= 'gdalwarp -dstnodata 0 -q -cutline %s -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff %s %s' % ('study_area_foscagno.shp', raster, outRaster)
    call (warp)
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to pythonize your whole script. So substitute your `for` loop with something like the following:

```
import os, fnmatch

def findRasters (path, filter):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
            yield file

for raster in findRasters(INPUT_FOLDER, '*.tif'):
    inRaster = INPUT_FOLDER + '/' + raster
    outRaster = OUTPUT_FOLDER + '/clip_' + raster
    cmd = 'gdalwarp -q -cutline %s -crop_to_cutline %s %s' % (CLIP, inRaster, outRaster)
    os.system(cmd)
```

**Note 1:** I'm supposing that your raster files are GeoTIFF (`*.tif`).
**Note 2:** `-of GTiff` is not needed in `cmd`, because it's the default output format in `gdalwarp`.

Answer (score 5):

Modified version of **umbe1987**`s solution for Linux users:

```
import os, fnmatch
from subprocess import call
call(["ls", "-l"])

inFolder= '/run/media/user/SOFT/LANDSAT/Bulk Order 595257/L8 OLI_TIRS/LC81840262015165LGN00/'
outFolder= '/run/media/user/SOFT/LANDSAT/Bulk Order 595257/summer_clipped/'
shp = '/run/media/user/SOFT/LANDSAT/Bulk Order 595257/vector/mask.shp'
os.chdir (inFolder)

def findRasters (path, filter):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, filter):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
            yield os.path.join (root, file)

for raster in findRasters (inFolder, '*.TIF'):
    (infilepath, infilename)= os.path.split (raster)
    print infilename
    outRaster= outFolder+ 'clip_'+ infilename
    print outRaster
    warp= 'gdalwarp -cutline \'%s\' -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha \'%s\' \'%s\'' % (shp, raster, outRaster)
    os.system(warp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version for GDAL >= 2.1 that does not use 'from subprocess call gdal'

```
import os, fnmatch
from osgeo import gdal
call(["ls", "-l"])

inFolder = "/Users/username/Documents/MassCropTest/"
outFolder =  "/Users/username/Documents/MassCropTest/OutputFolder/"
mask = "/Users/username/Documents/MassCropTest/Mask2.shp"
os.chdir (inFolder)

def findRasters (path, filter):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, filter):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
            yield os.path.join (root, file)


for raster in findRasters (inFolder, '*.tif'): #Find all tifs
        (infilepath, infilename)= os.path.split (raster)
        print(infilename)
        outRaster= outFolder+ 'clip_'+ infilename
        print(outRaster)
        warp= gdal.Warp(outRaster,raster, cutlineDSName = mask, dstNodata = 255)
```