# Clipping raster by shapefile in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, clip

Currently I am working with some satellite images (grib files) in pyqgis. As I want to work only with the cells in my study area, I need to clip the raster by a shapefile. I know I can do this by Raster tools in QGIS, but since I have a lot of rasters to work with, I wanted to use python and save time.

Perhaps somebody knows the pyqgis commands to do this?

I am new to QGIS and python.

Answer (score 7):

The raster tool of QGIS uses  GDAL commands

You can also use these GDAL commands ([gdalwrap](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) or [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html)) in a Python script, look at [how to for loop a folder to batch clip rasters by polygon using python and QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75086/how-to-for-loop-a-folder-to-batch-clip-rasters-by-polygon-using-python-and-qgis) or [Extract raster windows from satellite imagery with GDAL](http://invisibleroads.com/tutorials/gdal-raster-extract.html) and in pure Python [Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook: Python Clip a GeoTiff with Shapefile](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#clip-a-geotiff-with-shapefile)

But you can do the same thing without PyQGIS or GDAL with the Python module [PyShp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyshp/1.2.0): (Shapefile):  [GeospatialPython: Clip a Raster using a Shapefile](http://geospatialpython.com/2011/02/clip-raster-using-shapefile.html)

And you can also use [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html)  and [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) -> [Warping images with rasterio](http://sgillies.net/blog/2014/02/25/warping-images-with-rasterio.html)

Comment: The [GeospatialPython link](http://geospatialpython.com/2011/02/clip-raster-using-shapefile.html) you provide for a solution based on PyShp is wrong. That solution actually uses GDAL and no PyShp at all.