# QGIS 2.18.1 - Batch adding raster layers with Python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I create action, which adding raster from file (for a grid vector layer).
Now, I'll want to use python for batch adding raster layer for selected items.
How can I do it?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help in providing tips on how to add multiple raster layers: [For looping folder to batch clip rasters by polygon using python and QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75086/for-looping-folder-to-batch-clip-rasters-by-polygon-using-python-and-qgis)