# How to call "Clip Raster by Mask Layer" tool using QGIS console? (gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gdal, qgis-processing, qgis-3

I execute the followng code in QGIS 3.2.1 console, but `Clip Raster by Mask Layer` tool doesn't work - output file is not created.

Here is QGIS console output:

```
None # perhaps this None appears as a result of calling processing.run(...)
result = {'OUTPUT': 'W:\\MODIS\\tif_files\\MYD02QKM.A2018209.0820.006.2018209195116_tif_CLIPPED.tif'}
```

And here is the QGIS `Log Messanges`:

**Prosessing tab:**

```
2018-08-01T11:15:58     INFO    gdalwarp -ot Byte -of GTiff -tr 250.0 -250.0 -tap -cutline G:\!Download\!!MODIS\execute_files\cutter_ZERO.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstnodata 255.0 -co -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=LZW W:\MODIS\tif_files\MYD02QKM.A2018209.0820.006.2018209195116_tif.tif W:\MODIS\tif_files\MYD02QKM.A2018209.0820.006.2018209195116_tif_CLIPPED.tif
2018-08-01T11:15:58     INFO    GDAL command:
2018-08-01T11:15:58     INFO    gdalwarp -ot Byte -of GTiff -tr 250.0 -250.0 -tap -cutline G:\!Download\!!MODIS\execute_files\cutter_ZERO.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstnodata 255.0 -co -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=LZW W:\MODIS\tif_files\MYD02QKM.A2018209.0820.006.2018209195116_tif.tif W:\MODIS\tif_files\MYD02QKM.A2018209.0820.006.2018209195116_tif_CLIPPED.tif
2018-08-01T11:15:58     INFO    GDAL command output:
2018-08-01T11:15:58     INFO    ERROR 4: GTiff: No such file or directory

2018-08-01T11:15:58     INFO    GDAL execution console output
             ERROR 4: GTiff: No such file or directory

2018-08-01T11:15:58     INFO    Results: {'OUTPUT': 'W:\\MODIS\\tif_files\\MYD02QKM.A2018209.0820.006.2018209195116_tif_CLIPPED.tif'}
```

**OGR tab:**

```
2018-08-01T11:15:58     WARNING    Cannot open W:\MODIS\tif_files\MYD02QKM.A2018209.0820.006.2018209195116_tif.tif.()
```

**Python warning tab:**

```
2018-08-01T11:15:57     WARNING    warning:__console__:1: ResourceWarning:

             unclosed file 


             traceback: File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\console\console.py", line 575, in runScriptEditor
              self.tabEditorWidget.currentWidget().newEditor.runScriptCode()
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\console\console_editor.py", line 629, in runScriptCode
              .format(filename.replace("\\", "/"), sys.getfilesystemencoding()))
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\console\console_sci.py", line 635, in runCommand
              more = self.runsource(src)
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\console\console_sci.py", line 665, in runsource
              return super(ShellScintilla, self).runsource(source, filename, symbol)
              File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 75, in runsource
              self.runcode(code)
              File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
              exec(code, self.locals)
              File "", line 1, in
```

Calling the same tool from the QGIS interface with the same input files produces the expected results.

**How to call 'gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer' using QGIS console?**

Here is the code:

```
import os

def clip_raster_by_vector(input_raster, input_vector, output_raster, overwrite=False):
    if overwrite:
        if os.path.isfile(output_raster):
            os.remove(output_raster)

    if not os.path.isfile(input_raster):
        print ("File doesn't exists", input_raster)
        return None
    else:
        params = {'INPUT': input_raster,
                  'MASK': input_vector,
                  'NODATA': 255.0,
                  'ALPHA_BAND': False,
                  'CROP_TO_CUTLINE': True,
                  'KEEP_RESOLUTION': True,
                  'OPTIONS': '-of GTiff -co COMPRESS=LZW',
                  'DATA_TYPE': 0,  # Byte
                  'OUTPUT': output_raster,
                  }

        feedback = qgis.core.QgsProcessingFeedback()
        alg_name = 'gdal:cliprasterbymasklayer'
        print(processing.algorithmHelp(alg_name))
        result = processing.run(alg_name, params, feedback=feedback)
        return result


input_raster = r"W:\MODIS\tif_files\MYD02QKM.A2018209.0820.006.2018209195116_tif.tif"
output_raster = r"W:\MODIS\tif_files\MYD02QKM.A2018209.0820.006.2018209195116_tif_CLIPPED.tif"
input_vector = r"G:\!Download\!!MODIS\execute_files\cutter_ZERO.shp"
result = clip_raster_by_vector(input_raster, input_vector, output_raster, overwrite=True)
print('result =', result)
```

EDIT 1:

I have found a difference in calling `gdalwarp` with QGIS console and QGIS interface.

**QGIS console**

```
gdalwarp -ot Byte -of GTiff -tr 250.0 -250.0 -tap -cutline G:\!Download\!!MODIS\execute_files\cutter_ZERO.shp -crop_to_cutline -dstnodata 255.0 -co -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=LZW W:\MODIS\tif_files\MYD02QKM.A2018209.0820.006.2018209195116_tif.tif W:\MODIS\tif_files\MYD02QKM.A2018209.0820.006.2018209195116_tif_CLIPPED.tif
```

**QGIS interface**

```
gdalwarp -ot Byte -of GTiff -tr 250.0 -250.0 -tap -cutline path_to_data_file -crop_to_cutline -dstnodata 255.0 -co COMPRESS=LZW W:/MODIS/tif_files/MYD02QKM.A2018209.0820.006.2018209195116_tif.tif W:/MODIS/tif_files/MYD02QKM.A2018209.0820.006.2018209195116_tif_CLIPPED.tif
```

Comment: As a workaround solution this answer might help to execute tool using subprocess module: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/150680/35561

Comment: is there anything relevant shown in the log window?

Comment: @ndawson Sorry, forgot to add this. The question has been edited.

Comment: Actually I meant the QGIS log panel - i.e. click the "speech bubble" in the lower right, and check the different tabs for useful info

Comment: @ndawson Logs added. Strange but QGIS can't open the input file. As mentioned in OGR tab it receive wrong input path, somehow `.()` added at the end of the path string: `W:\MODIS\tif_files\MYD02QKM.A2018209.0820.006.2018209195116_tif.tif.()`

Comment: I think that's just the "end of sentence" ., and I'm not sure what the () is for. Anyway, the issue is originating from the gdal command -- that's where the failure is happening. Try running the gdal command that you see in the log in a command line window, and from there you should be able to tweak the command until you can identify the problem. My suspicion is that it's the ! symbols in the paths used.

Comment: @ndawson Thanks for you help! Problem were caused by incorrect `options` parameter here is the right one: 'OPTIONS': 'COMPRESS=LZW',

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem were caused by incorrect `options` parameter. Changing that line:

```
'OPTIONS': '-of GTiff -co COMPRESS=LZW',
```

to

```
 'OPTIONS': 'COMPRESS=LZW',
```

solved the problem.